# .NET: ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup deploy commands not being run for automatically created instances

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a .net MVC web app (MVC4, a mix between the new web-api and normal MVC). It's being hosted on the latest IIS Elastic Beanstalk cluster.

The way I'm uploading my application to Elastic Beanstalk is through the VS2012 AWS plugin. I'm not using the "git" method to upload since that doesn't seem to work on Windows due to max path name restrictions in windows git.

The app runs fine after you create a new cluster and keep it at a single node. Uploading new application versions to it also works.

The problems occur after Elastic Beanstalk adds or recreates any of the instances in the cluster. If you resize the cluster manually by increasing the minimum number of nodes, or change the VM type (from micro to small, for example), Elastic Beanstalk will create new nodes and add them to the cluster. These new nodes are 100% broken. They are running IIS but when you browse to them you just see the IIS default screen, not my web application. It's like these new nodes are simply not loading my web application.

This bug is 100% reproducible and happens every time Elastic Beanstalk creates any nodes after the initial cluster creation.

As it is, Elastic Beanstalk is completely broken for me. I need to scale this application up asap to at least 4 nodes and I have no idea how I'm going to do that with this buggy behavior.

I just reproduced this now to get a good test case for this report.
Through Visual Studio I published my app to a new load balanced environment of type Small.
Then through the EB web admin page I changed the minimum cluster count to 2.

The original instance: i-4664813e (ec2-54-227-153-42.compute-1.amazonaws.com)

The newly added instance: i-325f2056 (ec2-54-205-64-135.compute-1.amazonaws.com)

(you'll have to copy and paste those URLs into your browser since i can't post more than 2 links apparently)

You can see that the newly added instance is not working. It is loading the default IIS app and not my app (you should see "SV, SlotsVacation, slotsvacation, dev").

I compared the 2 log files from both instances and the problem seems to be here:

working log file:

```
cfn-hup.log:

2013-10-12 12:36:13,992 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 12:36:14,210 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 12:37:38,934 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 9c9388b0-3bac-412e-9936-3d89aa8f4297)
2013-10-12 12:37:38,934 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2013-10-12 12:41:11,049 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2013-10-12 12:41:15,651 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: e46a7650-94df-4481-afba-7c6fb47c98ef)
2013-10-12 12:41:15,651 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2013-10-12 12:41:43,311 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2013-10-12 12:43:09,298 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 12:43:09,453 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 12:45:40,786 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 12:45:41,005 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 12:45:41,177 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 3b1df0b0-fd54-4ddc-827b-6527dddc9d70)
2013-10-12 12:45:41,177 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2013-10-12 12:46:48,710 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2013-10-12 13:06:02,119 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 81c8dab0-e142-4fb9-bad2-1c4bfa4a3be5)
2013-10-12 13:06:02,119 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
```

You can see it receives 4 ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup commands, and the IDs of the commands match up to AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext._API._Commands.CMD-Startup, Hook-PreAppDeploy, etc. The commands that seem to actually deploy my web application.

The non-working log file:

```
cfn-hup.log:

2013-10-12 13:16:48,661 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 13:16:48,848 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 13:22:22,316 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 13:22:22,551 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 13:24:54,128 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2013-10-12 13:24:54,408 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2013-10-12 13:24:59,588 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 69acfccd-2a1b-4535-b22d-377870cb4a9c)
2013-10-12 13:24:59,604 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
```

You can see that it only receives 1 command, and that one is actually a CMD-TailLogs command so it's not related to the app deployment at all. So it seems like the problem is that the newly created instance is simply not receiving the commands to deploy the web app.

Here is the full log file dump from each instance:

original working instance: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59304/logs/resources%252Fenvironments%252Flogs%252Ftail%252Fe-kgcjtidtmm%252Fi-4664813e%252FTailLogs-1381583168.out.txt

new broken instance: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59304/logs/resources%252Fenvironments%252Flogs%252Ftail%252Fe-kgcjtidtmm%252Fi-325f2056%252FTailLogs-1381584345.out.txt

Any ideas how I can fix this? Things I could try? Is it a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

My app is pretty plain vanilla. I've only added 1 .ebextension, newrelic.config, which is straight from the new relic documentation.

Comment: It looks like you're rebooting the instance in the container-commands. Instead, try moving the reboot command as the last command, with a "waitAfterCompletion: forever" to the command spec, and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @JimFlanagan tried that, no change in the behavior. My application still fails to deploy properly. You'd think a system restart would be properly supported in EB.

Comment: @tayl0rs ever get somewhere here? it's 2022 and beanstalk still has this issue! won't run commands defined in AWSEBAutoScalingGroup when bringing up an instance (in my case copy a file from S3 onto the new instance)